# My table is not created in database

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am new in Laravel and now using v4.2. I want to make a table using migrations. Everything is correct. Migration also created. But **no table is found in db except migrations table**. First in command prompt I wrote `php artisan migrate:make create_users_table`. Then migration table crated. Then in migration file I wrote following code

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function($table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('username');
        $table->string('password');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}


public function down()
{
    Schema::drop('users');
}
```

then if I try `php artisan migrate`, command prompt says nothing to migrate.

Comment: A recommendation, use `Schema::dropIfExists('users');` in your down function. Also, what does your `app->config->app.php` and `app->config->database.php` look like? Are you using the right connection settings?

Comment: app->config->app.php the key is automatically set up and app->config->database.php i set my da name, host name and user name. I am working  now localhost.

Comment: Thank you Tim Lewis. Its working now.

Comment: @Salman:- add the answer to this question, then accept and close the question

Answer (score 0):

Try referencing the environment. first run:

```
php artisan env
```

and see the result. If it is development, for example, try running the migrations like:

```
php artisan migrate --env=development
```